# Does Drools Salience Have Performance Impacts?

Tags: performance, drools

For example, if I have 1 million fact objects, going through a set of rules, where the execution order of the rules is irrelevant. Will there be any performance difference between:

1. Explicitly assign different salience values to each rule
2. Use the default salience value (0) or all the rules are with the same salience value?

Just for the curiosity, because I just heard that the latter one performs better.

---

I did some benchmarking myself. The result shows that the different salience approach does have some overhead, and increases the total processing time (not much though), however the time spent on fact object processing seems the same.

Not sure if this observation meets the underlying code logic.

I should thank you both for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Drools 6. Each rule match (also called activation or rule instantiation) for a given rule is added to a bidirectional linked list. Firing for that rule is a matter of iterating that list, firing each rule in turn.

Each rule to evaluate is placed on a BinaryHeapQueue and rules are popped in turn, evaluated, the linked list produced, and then it iterated to attempt firing.

If there are a large number of rule matches, per rule, then the cost of the heap queue will not be noticeable. If you have a low number of rule matches per rule, but a large number of rules, you'll probably see a 10% (this is a guess) or so overhead in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The Agenda, i.e., the list containing all rule activations, is ordered by salience. It is clear that maintaining a linked list ordered by some criterion is more costly than an unordered one. Of course, the implementation tries to be as efficient as possible, see the code org.drools.core.util.BinaryHeapQueue.

Using a different salience for each rule would be an ingredient for the worst-case scenario. Another one would be the interleaving of inserts and firings, which could either render the different salience values harmles or create bad or worst-case scenarios.